# Unexpected result in Power Bi Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, powerbi

When I try to run the below  script on a power bi data set

```
import pandas as pd 
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 
sia=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 
dataset['polairty scores'] =dataset['Column1'].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)['compound'])
```

I get the attached image as a result

[image: Result table]

I expect to see this table

[image: source table]

with a new column that has a score in each row

Comment: What happens when you click the two split arrows in the top right of the `Value` column header?

Comment: it gives me the option to select one of three items Column1 column2 or polarity scores all 3 is selected but if I select only 1 the table displays the same

Comment: Select all columns - you are wanting it to expand the table in the column.

Comment: still gives the same result

Comment: Not sure what "same results" means. Click on the actual cell that has `Table` in green, then at the bottom, a data preview should show what this table looks like. Share a screen  grab of that.

Comment: I See now thanks very much sorry got a bit lost there